# Is there a better code for printing fibonacci series?

Tags: c

Is the algorithm below the best way of generating the Fibonacci series? Or is there a better approach?

This is my C program to print fibonacci series.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,i,n,t;
    printf("Enter the number");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    i=1;
    n=0;

    for(t=1;t<=a;t++)
    {
        n=n+i;
        i=n-i;
        printf("%d",n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: **bold** a better logic in for loop

Comment: Please check that my edit of your question is right. I've tried to clarify the question, because it's getting downvotes at the moment (even though it seems quite clear to me).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64133793/12817546.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also to have a more efficient way to calculate Go if you watch closely, you'll see the following sequence:

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 ...

The formula for mapping the Fibonacci sequence is:

[image]

Then if you code this (Go):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci() func() int {
    first, second := 0, 1
    return func() int {
        ret := first
        first, second = second, first+second
        return ret
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

You'll see the numbers till 100 and without using conditionals for **base cases**. I hope that approach helped you understand better the problem!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This is optimal in terms of time complexity and space complexity, and much faster than the naive recursive algorithm, which is exponential in terms of run time.

It does look as though your assignments in your loop aren't quite right, though. You want

```
int oldi = i;
i = n+i;
n = oldi;
```

HOWEVER, your approach has a crucial weakness, which is that you will quickly overflow the bounds of an `int`. Even with a 64-bit value, you'll get wrong answers by the time you hit f(100).

To get correct answers with arbitrary indices, you will need an arbitrary size integer library.

A related issue came up yesterday with [calculating the Fibonacci series in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822459/3933089).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @RogerFernandezGuri's excellent answer, a possibly more readable answer in Go for printing a Fibonacci series.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := 0, 1
    h := func() int {
        a, b = b, a+b
        return b-a
    }
    fibonacci := func() func() int { return h }
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f()) //0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this answer extends the accepted answer that is in Go.

Comment: Both the question and accepted answer are 6 years old! If you have something new to say (always good) say something new and relevant

Comment: In my opinion this does say something new and relevant. Also "Stack Overflow is a wiki first".  See https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up.