# How do I make this Fibonacci sequence generator more elegant?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fib_seq() func() int {
    n0, n1 := 0, 1

    return func() int {
        result := n0
        n0, n1 = n1, n0 + n1
        return result
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fib_seq()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

This is my Fibonacci sequence generator. The definition of `result` is unwanted (but necessary).

I wonder is there a way to execute `x, y = y, x + y` after `return`?

Comment: You can do `defer` but it would be ugly.

Comment: Check out the [example](https://play.golang.org/p/A0nH96VB4S) from golang.org

Comment: What you have done is pretty good. There is another way of Fibonacci calculation. You can do it using matrix. It is less elegant from programming view but it is much more elegant from mathematical view. I have an example of implementation on Python  https://gist.github.com/I159/ab818dfe0415d415d7314c57e17f0460#file-matrix_fibo-py-L62-L106 . If it seems an interesting for you, I could translate it to Go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64133793/12817546.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `defer`:

```
func fib_seq() func() int {
    n0, n1 := 0, 1

    return func() int {
        defer func() {
            n0, n1 = n1, n0 + n1
        }()

        return n0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Named return. But what you have is already readable enough.

```
func fib_seq() func() int {
    n0, n1 := 0, 1

    return func() (r int) {
        r, n0, n1 = n0, n1, n0 + n1
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd prefer the following (for readability):

```
type fib struct{ n0, n1 int }

func (f *fib) next() int {
    defer func() { 
        f.n0, f.n1 = f.n1, f.n0+f.n1 
    }()
    return f.n0
}

func main() {
    fib := &fib{0, 1}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(fib.next())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Elegant" means different things to different people. To some it may mean "conciseness," and to others it may mean "simplicity," or "readability."

Here is my take on it:

```
public class Fibonacci {

    private static int x;
    private static int y;
    private static int z;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        z = 0;

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        while (z < 100) {
            z = x + y;
            System.out.println(z);
            x = y;
            y = z;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, I favor readability over sophistication :)

Comment: I agree with you... you just didn't do it in `Go` :)