# What should I change in the code to generate a fibonacci sequence starting from 0 1 1

Tags: algorithm, go, fibonacci

I've searched older questions, there are tons of them. However I couldn't find the answer to my case.

```golang
func fibonacci() func() int {
    y := 0
    z := 1

    return func () int {

        res := y + z
        y = z
        z = res

        return res

    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

This produces 1 2 3 5 8

What should I change (as little as possible) to get 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 ?

Actually I managed to solve that if initial `y` and `z` were like this:

```
    y := -1
    z := 1
```

But that's a fortunate hack, and I want a logical solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question another way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64133793/12817546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to return res to this:

```
 return func () int {

    res := y
    y = z
    z = res + z

    return res

}
```

This way you output the initial values first, and calculate the next values. Your current solution overwrites the initial values before they are returned.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci returns a function that returns
// successive Fibonacci numbers.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a, b := 0, 1
    return func() (f int) {
        if a < 0 {
            panic("overflow")
        }
        f, a, b = a, b, a+b
        return f
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uYHEK_ZgE6K

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: Interesting, but was a bit hard for me as a go newbie :-) However, your answer finally gave me the real use case of using multiple variable assignment (`f, a, b = a, b, a+b`)

Answer (score 1):

If you added:

```
x := y
```

and changed the return statement to

```
return x
```

you would be returning the initial `y := 0` value, instead of the computed `res := y + z`, so returning the values 2 earlier in the sequence, giving you `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...`

(But I wouldn’t consider the `-1, 1` initializer a hack.)

Comment: Nice, thanks! But I slightly prefer the other answer because it doesn't introduce the new variable